# Bizarre "No such file or directory" error when running a command within a docker container

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, docker, terminal

I am trying to run a very simple python file that simply prints "woof" within a docker container. As far as I know I have created a docker container called:

```
c5d3c4c383d1
```

I then run the following command, in an attempt to tell myself what directory I am running things from in docker:

```
sudo docker run c5d3c4c383d1 pwd
```

This returns the following value:

```
/
```

Which I assume to be my root directory, so I go to my root directory. Typing pwd shows:

```
/
```

I then create a file called meow.py via the nano command and enter in this a single line that is:

```
 print("Woof!")
```

I save this and confirm this is in the / directory with an ls command.

I then enter the following:

```
 sudo docker run c5d3c4c383d1 python meow.py
```

Which returns:

```
python: can't open file 'meow.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I don't understand this. Obviously I am not in the root directory when running a command with the docker as the meow.py file is DEFINETLY in the root directory but it is saying this file cannot be found. What the heck... As i said when I run pwd within the docker container it says i am in the / directory, but I cannot be given this file not found error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

docker is a container ... thats its root directory ... think of it like a totally different machine that you would normally ssh into... try something like this

```
docker run -it c5d3c4c383d1 bash
```

thats basically like you have just ssh'd into your remote machine

go ahead and try some commands (`ls,pwd,etc`)

now run `echo print("hello world")>test.py`

now run `ls` you should see your test.py ... go ahead and run it with `python test.py`

now you can `exit` you container ... if you launch the same container again you should still have your test.py file there... although i think its more common that people write a dockerfile that sets up their environment and then they just treat each session as disposable, as opposed to keeping the same container

Comment: I see! Conceptually this makes a ton of sense. Sadly when I try and run docker -it run c5d3c4c383d1 bash, i am told unknown shorthand flag: 'i' in -it. when i remove the -it flag i do not appear to connect to the docker container. thoughts?

Comment: @majotcoder, it's `docker run -it`, not `docker -it run`

Comment: thanks! it seems the changes I make to the image when I connect to it like this do not save. Any idea how I could get them to save?